# xna game in landscape i want to add microsoft ads in potrairt form

Tags: windows-phone-7

How do I add portrait-layouted ads to a XNA game in landscape form?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a lot of support right now for the orientation of the ads but there is other ways of writing your own design to the ads.

[WP7 ads for XNA (AppHub)](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/69363/423447.aspx)